# I am writing the below code in selenium to click the Captcha checkbox and below error is showing

Tags: java, selenium, captcha

[click the captcha checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eAnn.png)

[inspect the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4KWW.png)

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-eye-slash']")).click();

Comment: what is the error? Try with fa.fa-eye-slash

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Hi captcha is from google and that purpose is cant automate by 3 rd party any tools so don't try to automate captcha
CAPTCHA, short for Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart, is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try! There are two primary strategies to get around CAPTCHA checks:

Disable CAPTCHAs in your test environment
Add a hook to allow tests to bypass the CAPTCHA